# Can "-like" be an adverb?

Tags: adverbs

Dumbledore gave his wand a little flick as if he was trying to get a fly off the end and a long golden ribbon flew out of it, which rose high above the tables and twisted itself **snake-like** into words.

From Harry Potter

If it's an adjective, should it be "in a snake-like way"? Why does an adjective came out out of the blue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it's an adverb because it is describing the manner of the main verb, 'twisted'. The ribbon [noun] twisted [verb] in a 'snake-like' manner.

There's normally no need to qualify an adverb by saying something like "in an [x] *way/manner*". When you recognise an adverb and the verb it modifies it is normally clear what kind of adverb it is (of degree, frequency, manner etc).

An alternative way to describe this twisting action would have been to use '*snake*' as a verb (eg "*the ribbon snaked into the air*").

Comment: Why can't it be an adjective referring to "itself" (i.e. "a long golden ribbon")?

Comment: @BillJ Adjectives describe nouns, adverbs describe verbs. *Twisted*, in this context, is a verb - it is the action of the ribbon magically turning in the air. The ribbon itself isn't 'snake-like', otherwise it would say "*the golden, snake-like ribbon twisted into the air*". It is the action; the way it moves, which is why the adverb only appears after it begins to move.

Comment: So, in, for example "The thieves left empty-handed" and "They served the coffee blindfolded", how would you treat "empty-handed"  and "blindfolded"?

Comment: @BillJ Strawman. You tell me how a golden ribbon is like a snake while stationary.

Comment: Just answer my question. Are "empty-handed" and "blindfolded" adverbs, or what?

Comment: @BillJ Blindfolded is a verb, as in "*Bill blindfolded himself accidentally*". And in this example, 'accidentally' is an adverb because it describes the manner in which this hypothetical Bill blindfolded himself.

Comment: Actually, in the example I gave, "blindfolded" is an adjective functioning as a predicative adjunct with the subject "they" as predicand ("blindfolded" describes the referent of "they"). And it's an adjunct because it's a modifier in clause structure. The same analysis applies to "empty-handed" in my other example.

Comment: @BillJ But I'm not interested in your example because it isn't the same as the OP's. I suspect you constructed it to double-down on your erroneous argument, which is why you wouldn't answer my question which was directly on-topic.

Comment: Sorry, but you analysed my examples completely wrongly, which casts doubts on your ability to parse sentences in general.